# How and why do we use the "ne" of negative but without an attempt to express it ?

Tags: grammaire

I some cases, we use the "ne" of negation but it doesn't refer to the negative meaning itself.

For instance, we say "je vais faire cela avant qu'il ne le fasse "

Why we use it and in which cases do we have to ?!

Answer (score 1):

This is called a *ne explétif*.

Using it is common in written French and non colloquial spoken French, but quite rare ortherwise.

It is only used in some cases of *proposition subordonnée* introduced by a conjunction using *que*.

Its origin is not clear but the most probable reason is that French followed the already existing usage in Latin.

The *ne explétif* is never mandatory and can be removed without affecting the meaning of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

"Ne" can be use as non-négative in sustained langage.

[Ne explétif](http://Ne%20expl%C3%A9tif)

[Ne explétif, Expletive ne](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/ne-expletif/)

[LE NE EXPLÉTIF](http://bescherelle.ca/le-ne-expletif/)

[Ne explétif](https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/fle/ne-expletif-95.php)